# Typo3 installation on PHP4

Tags: typo3, php4

Does anybody know if it's possible to install Typo3 on PHP4? I've looked up the [packages-page](http://typo3.org/download/packages/), but i haven't found anything yet.

Many thanks in regards!

Comment: Last compatible version was 4.1. Since 4.2 - no way to get TYPO3 with PHP4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to install any recent versions. TYPO3 4.6 requires **PHP 5.3+** and even TYPO3 4.4 requires **PHP 5.2+**. Some older versions obviously used to run on PHP 4 but all versions prior to TYPO3 4.4 are outdated, not maintained and insecure.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want PHP4! ;-) a bit sarcastic, but please change your mind / your boss's mind! It's out of support since ages and basically sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it's not. The system requirements for the latest version state PHP5:
http://typo3.org/about/system-requirements/